# Gluon Mobile: Access JavaDoc from within NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, gluon, gluon-mobile

I would like to access the Javadoc documentation of Gluon using the NetBeans context menu option **Show Javadoc**:

[image: NetBeans context menu]

This fails with **Cannot perform Show Javadoc here**:

[image: Cannot perform Show Javadoc here]

Showing the Javadoc for classes belonging to the Java standard library (for example javafx.scene.Scene) works as expected. Hence, I need to set the url to the Gluon Mobile documentation (http://docs.gluonhq.com/mobile/javadoc) manually. As Gluon projects are managed by Gradle, the project settings dialog appears to have no way of specifying an url. As a workaround I tried setting the url as part of the Javadoc urls for the Java core libs (as I said: workaround) but this did not help either.

As an alternative, I tried downloading the sources from within NetBeans but this did not help, too.

[image]

So, the questions boils down to: Where can I specify the url to the Gluon Mobile Javadoc so that NetBeans will pick it up? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gluon Mobile Javadoc is available at the repository with the regular jar (i.e, for the current [3.0.0](http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/gluonhq/charm-glisten/3.0.0/)).

The problem with the gradle plugin for NetBeans is that it doesn't download it.

A possible solution is, according to the plugin [author](https://github.com/kelemen/netbeans-gradle-project/issues/179), this one:

For every Gluon project, edit the `build.gradle` file, and insert this, right after the jfxmobile plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
idea.module.downloadJavadoc = true
```

Save the file, and reload the project (right click on the Project name -> Reload Project).

Now, on the Dependencies folder, right click and select Download Sources.

After a few seconds, the javadoc jar will be added to the project, and you will have the required inline help for Gluon Mobile.

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Works as described. Thanks a lot.