# How to access Gluon JavaDoc in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, gluon

I'm having the same problem accessing the Gluon JavaDoc like described in this question: [Gluon Mobile: Access JavaDoc from within NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38565856/gluon-mobile-access-javadoc-from-within-netbeans), but in Eclipse Neon.

Eclipse plugin is added to the buildscript:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases' }
}

apply plugin: 'eclipse'

eclipse {
    classpath {
        downloadSources = true
        downloadJavadoc = true
}
```

}

all javadocs but Gluon are showing up.

I've tried to run `gradle eclipse` which downloaded the docs, but added all gradle dependencies twice. In gradleClassPathContainer and eclipseClassPathContainer, and the javadoc is still missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the steps I've followed to make it work.

- Create the project with the Gluon plugin.
- Edit the `build.gradle` script and add the `eclipse` plugin, and include the option to download the javadoc.

Add it after the jfxmobile plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
eclipse {
    classpath {
        downloadJavadoc = true
    }
}
```

- Save and refresh the gradle project.
- The Gradle tasks should contain now the `eclipse` task, run it.
- Edit the project properties, select Java Build Path. You will see the Charm jar on top.  If you click the arrow, you should see that it already includes the javadoc link:

[image: java build path]

- It is duplicated under `Projects and External Dependencies`, but this jar doesn't include the javadoc one. You can remove safely this node. Close the dialog.
- Now the Charm jar will be include under `Referenced libraries`.

[image]

- And you will have the javadoc available.

[image: javdoc]

Comment: Aaaah! I removed the duplicate jar entries in referenced libraries instead the jars in project and external dependencies, which didn't work. Following your answer it works perfectly. Thank you once again!

Comment: I don't see an eclipse task in gradle tasks after changing the build file. under which folder is it supposed to be?

Comment: Nevermind. Had to restart the workspace. Refresh Gradle Project wasn't enough. Leaving this comment in case someone else needs it.